# How to position a block in the gutter of a grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, 960.gs

I am learning to use a grid system such as 960.gs or Twitter's Bootstrap.

If I want to position a content block (e.g. an ) with its left side starting in the middle of a gutter between two columns, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, a gutter is supposed to be empty. So, if you can't use basic [scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) to do what you need, and you really want the left side of your content to start from the middle of a gutter, you might need to add a CSS class with something like:

```
margin-left: -1em;
```

You might need to change the negative `-1em` value for it to be half of the gutter's width of course.

Not pretty, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Ismael, thanks for your input! I am also wondering about what effect it would be in case of a responsive design.